# Is it possible to create a subsite in another site collection using workflows?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online

I am required to programatically create a sub-site in another site-collection from a workflow attached to a list. Has anyone a solution for this problem?

I am able to create a sub-site in my site collection using rest API but I am not able to do the same for another site collection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this exists only two ways:

1. Create your own custom web service, host them for example in azure cloud and call it from workflow.
2. Use 3rd party solution, for example you can use [Create Web](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/administration/#CreateWeb) actions from [Workflow Actions Pack](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/). This product distributed by my company and I'm member of dev team.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own custom code activity in your workflow and in that activity you can use Sharepoint server object model to create site in any other site collection.

Comment: You can't use server object model in sharepoint online.

Comment: I was not aware about the fact they are using Sharepoint Online. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Sorry I didnt mention earlier, I am working on Sharepoint Cloud.